# Clarification on the three things you need to check to prove a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In my linear algebra class I am said to be able to prove a subset is a subspace is to prove three things:

1. the set is not an empty set
2. closure under addition
3. closure under multiplication

however, everywhere I see online the 1st rule is to make sure it contains the 0 vector. Why are these rules okay to interchange (I don't really see the correlation between them)?

Comment: Closure under multiplication means in particular $0\vec v=\vec 0$ is in the subspace

Comment: If it contains the zero vector then it is not an empty set.  If it is not an empty set and it is closed under multiplication, then it follows that whatever guaranteed element $x$ in the set there is since it is closed under multiplication $0\cdot x$ should also be in the set.

Comment: As an aside, they can be replaced with $\forall x,y\in V\neq \emptyset$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb K$ you have $\alpha x + \beta y\in V$.  This covers all three conditions in one statement.